# Minimum_over_time doesn't seem to get the desired results

Tags: prometheus

I set up a query to get the minimum value over 24 hours for one of our metrics, I am displaying it as a singlestat in grafana.

It will work sometimes and then work for a while before going back to 'No data'. There is data going through so I expected it should return something.

```
topk(1,min_over_time(application_processingtime{quantile="0.5"}[24h])) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would presume there are periods when the minimums are all 0, in which case that query would return nothing. Try removing the `>0`.

`min(min_over_time(application_processingtime{quantile="0.5"}[24h])` would also be a more typical way to write that query.